# How to use a custom font in a GTK application?

Tags: c, gtk

My C program uses a custom CSS file to define its GTK style:

```
GFile* style = g_file_new_for_path("style.css");
gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(GTK_CSS_PROVIDER(provider), style, NULL);
```

In this file, no `font-family` declaration is made.

When I inspect my application on Linux using `GTK_DEBUG=interactive`, I find that the program's font is set to my system default, "Ubuntu":

[image]

My question is: how can I change this default behavior and use a custom font imported from a `.ttf` file in my entire application?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16598777/16775594) would be a duplicate, except for the fact that the answer's Python-specific. Just putting that out there, before anyone flags this as a duplicate.